# Convert string to date in map loop - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to convert a date returned to me as a string (format: "2020-06-15T12:41:16+00:00") into a date object.

So I get my list of items in a fetchResults() function, and I thought I could do the conversion at the time of the .map in the return, only I don't really see the syntax I could use...

Anyone have an idea?

My component react :

```
const ResultList = ({userId}) => {

    const [resultsList, setResultList] = useState({})

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchResults()
    }, [userId])

    const fetchResults = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await resultsAPI.findResultsByUser(userId)
            setResultList(data)
            setLoading(false)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    return(
        <>
            {!loading && 
                <>
                    <h3 className="resultCount">You have {resultsList.length} results</h3>
                    <ul className="resultsList">
                        {resultsList.map(result => {
                            return(
                                <li key={result.id} className="resultItem">
                                    <span>{result.resultDate}</span> //HERE CONVERT STRING TO DATE
                                    <span>{result.Maturity}</span>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </>
            }

        </>
    )
}

export default ResultList
```

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try `new Date(result.resultDate)`? However this will not help you much as Date object will be converted to string again for display purpose. So the question is, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You will not be able to render `Date`-object anyways. Is there any particular reason why you need to do that? Do you need to convert your date string to some other format?

Comment: new Date(result.resultDate.split("T")[0]), will this work for you?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I understand that, yes... I'd need to get the day in a thong, finally get a date in text form... But I think I'll settle for that.

Comment: @Rajesh Date(result.resultDate) to convert to date format in the display . All you had to do was remove the new... I'll try to convert it before putting it in the state, so I can getDay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/). You can able to convert a date string to any desired date format. For that you need to know the current date format of a date string

```
import moment from "moment";    
let resultDate = '2020-06-15 17:44:18'; // which is YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

<span>{moment(resultDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').format('MM-DD-YYYY')}</span> // It will return 06-15-2020
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of "moment"... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<li key={result.id} className="resultItem">
 <span> {new Date(`${result.resultDate}`).toDateString()}</span> // use template literals
  <span>{result.Maturity}</span>
```

Use this will defenitly work.